# What's the advantage of using delegate to transfer values between viewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have two viewControllers, vcA and vcB.
When I want to transfer values to vcA from vcB, I use delegate like this:

```
//vcB.swift
protocol TransferDelegate {
    func transferValue(msg: String)
}

var delegate: TransferDelegate!

//vcA.swift
class vcA: UIViewController {
}

extension vcA: TransferDelegate {
    func transferValue(msg: String){
        //xxxxxxx
  }
}
```

When vcA push vcB,then `vcb.delegate = self`

When vcB want to transfer values, then `delegate.transferValue(msg)`

My question is what if I transfer vcA's instance self to vcB instead of set delegate like this:

```
//vcB.swift
class vcB: UIViewController {
    var vca: vcA!

    func transferValues(msg: String) {
        vca.msg = msg
    }
}

//vcA.swift
vcb.vca = self
```

I have tried both two methods, both of them can work.

So why we use the first method rather than the second?

What's the difference between then or what's the advantage of the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using a delegate is that `vcB` doesn't have (or need) any knowledge of the specific object type acting as the delegate. And this in turn makes it much simpler for `vcB` to be used by more than just `vcA`. It makes your classes less coupled and much more flexible.

Imagine of a `UITableView` only worked with a specific type of data source and delegate instead of allowing for anything that conforms to the proper protocols to act as a data source and delegate. This is no different.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't know the details of vcA so vcA should realize the protocol. What vcB do is only to tranfer the value, right?

Comment: Correct. `vcB` is designed (with the delegate) to be able to tell someone (anyone that is the delegate) that it has a message. That's all it needs. It doesn't (and shouldn't) care who it is as long as it implements the method of the delegate protocol.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol TransferDelegate {
    func transferValue(msg: String)
}
```

The good thing is you can reuse this delegate method in other vcs. 
Now you have `vcA` and `vcB` to do things. Maybe in the future you need something similar in other vcs.

Answer (score 0):

See when you are using delegate you can only access that particular method of that particular `viewController`. But if you save the whole instance in the vc2 you can access or change any of the properties or functions of that class. Might be which you don't want to allow the vc2 to access.